Moving down the isr_vector in stm32 with GCC
I need to move the isr_vector to make room for two variables I need to store there.
I have tried this in the linker script
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 92K
RAM2 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 32K
FLASH0 (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 4K
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN = 0x08001000, LENGTH = 1020K
my_ram (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20017000, LENGTH = 4K
}
/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* CUSOTM SECTION */
  .myBufBlock(NOLOAD) :

  {

    KEEP(*(.myRAM)) /* keep my variable even if not referenced */

  } > my_ram

    .crcBlock :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.myCrcSection)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH0

  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

And changed the offset to 0x1000:
SCB->VTOR = VECT_TAB_BASE_ADDRESS | VECT_TAB_OFFSET;
VECT_TAB_OFFSET = 0x1000;
VECT_TAB_BASE_ADDRESS = 0x08000000UL;

When I do this the program doesnt start on the stm32, what am I doing wrong?

Where do you change vector table? in main()? Do you even reach main? Can you blink LED? After all, basic blink program doesn't require interrupts, so having a blinking LED would mean that at least startup worked correctly. You didn't show where the executable .text resides. Where does your normal executable code actually go?

Wouldn't it be smarter to move your custom variables instead of insisting on "because of reasons-...". There cannot possibly be anything more important in the MCU than the vector table, so I never get why everyone insists on moving it around.

At the very least your reset vector has to be at the start of flash, otherwise how will the CPU know which instruction to execute first?

Your idea is wrong

I realized that I need to let the Isr_vector be first in memory and then put my data and then the rest of the user code.

This isn't possible - the initial stack pointer is stored at offset 0 into the flash (*), and the reset vector is at offset 4.
When you power on your system, the CPU will always load the SP and PC from these offsets, so it can start running your code. There is no way to change that. (You can move the vector table later, once your code has started, but not before.)
I'd suggest putting your CRC or whatever other data you have at some fixed offset after the vector table.
(*) Note that you can use the boot pins (and boot pin configuration registers) to map SRAM or the system bootloader at address 0x00000000, but that doesn't help you here.
